# Deeplinking with SWFAddress and Facebook connect

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, deep-linking, swfaddress

After prompting the user for the login and submitting it's details, my application appears in the facebook lightbox instead of the browser window.
This is not the case when I remove the SWFAddress params (all the info after the hash in the URL bar).
Is it possible to tell the API to ignore the info after the hash or is there a way i can determine the redirect URL myself?
Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution,
using an absolute instead of relative URL to reference the xd_receiver.htm file did the trick

```
fbInit("flashcontent", "9f4fa6e0e551630e597440c6a4118243", "/xd_receiver.htm");
```